Hide or Mask URL from an m3u file
I created an m3u file using notepad++ but I can't figure out how to hide the URL of the video source (YouTube). The YouTube livestream is unlisted and no one would be able to view it from YouTube unless they have the link but if they open the m3u file via notepad, they would be able to watch it directly from YouTube.
I haven't tried anything as I'm not knowledgeable on what to do.
